# is there any log showing when a server was installed?

Tags: server, log

I have an old ubuntu server, I know the kernel version, Ubuntu release etc, but Im curious about when the system was first installed, I know it has been upgraded numerous times. Is there any utility or log that keeps track of when a system starts its life?

Comment: Check out the contents of /var/log/installer/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the files in `/var/log/installer/*`.

Those were generated during the initial system installation. Their contents should give you all kinds of interesting information, but to find out the installation date, it should be enough to even just look at the file creation/modification timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The very first date of your very first log shows the installation.

However, since [logrotate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/logrotate.8.html) is installed by default, you'll have to look at its configuration to see if logs were mailed anywhere or retained anywhere, else restoration of  the original log data from your original backup is refquired, since it only retains the last four logs.

You might also generate a list of all files on your system, then filter for the oldest file which did not migrate from a previous system; try running this from the root: `find . | xargs ls -lrt | head -1`